# Android. Кнопка "назад" при использовании fragments

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть небольшое приложение, одно активити и штук 7 фрагментов, которые в нем располагаются, для перехода к предыдущему фрагменту использую addToBackStack, все работает прекрасно по аппаратной кнопке back. Но не понимаю как в action bar добавить кнопку назад, что бы по клику возвращала на предыдущей фрагмент.

Comment: код активити покажите

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Добавить кнопку Назад: `actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`

Метод, возвращающий к предыдущему фрагменту:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; 

public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
        fm.popBackStack();
    else
        finish();
}
```

Обработчик кнопки Назад:

```
import android.view.MenuItem;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: В вашей реализации ```onBackPressed()``` если фрагментов в стеке не останется, то приложение так и останется на первом фрагменте и выйти из него по кнопке ```back``` будет нельзя.

Comment: Кнопка назад добавилась, но там показывается стрелка даже когда с стеке ничего нет, как можно ее убрать если стек пуст?

Comment: @FredGan Вы уверены, что вам это надо? Обычно кнопка Назад показывается всегда и, когда стек состояний пуст, она по нажатию закрывает приложение.

Comment: @temq Учёл ваше замечание. Посмотрите новую реализацию, теперь будет выходить из приложения по кнопке Назад?

Comment: Да, теперь все хорошо, только обычно метод ```onBackPressed``` переопределяется в ```Activity``` и тогда в ```else``` ветке можно просто вызвать ```super.onBackPressed()```